# ROS Hydro/Indigo with Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now that Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS is released, is it advisable to upgrade or are there any known issues running ROS with the new Ubuntu version? I haven't seen many questions-answers regarding Ubuntu 14.04.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189780/ros-hydro/indigo-with-ubuntu-14.04.1-?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Indigo is stable and ready for users. There haven't been many changes since Hydro, so upgrading should be fairly straightforward; see the [Indigo migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration) for details.

That said, upgrading Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 has been giving people trouble (Ubuntu migrations with third-party packages tend to). If you can, I recommend installing Ubuntu from scratch instead of upgrading. If you can't or don't want to do a full, clean install, I recommend removing all previous versions of ROS (from debs; you can keep your local workspace) and running an `apt-get autoremove` **BEFORE** you upgrade Ubuntu. This should help bring the system back to a semi-stock state so that the upgrade can run cleanly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2